# Is there a way to mirror and duplicate in one action?

Tags: objects, workflow, mirror

I have this cube:
[image: cube]

When I mirror it around the x-axis I get this:
[image: bad mirror]

but I want this, so that the object is mirrored and duplicated:
[image: good mirror]

Currently, I can do that by copy-pasting the cube then mirroring the duplicate cube (leaving the original cube in place), but it feels like there should be a better way.

**How do I mirror an object such that it is duplicated, leaving the original in place?**

Comment: Use empty and **Mirror** modifier with that empty set as mirror object. *Or* **Array** modifier with that empty set as *Offset* object.

Comment: Set 3D cursor to the center with [Shift]+[S] and set it as the pivot point with [`.`] (period key), then use [Shift]+[D] > [S] > [X] > `-1`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a [mirror modifier](http://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/modifiers/generate/mirror.html).

All you need to do is add the mirror modifier, and set its *Axis* to Y... 
[image: mirror modifier settings]
Assuming you have the object origin at the scene center, and your cube positioned where you want it.
[image: object origin]

Comment: This will not create a new instance of the mesh though.

Comment: no, but depending on what you are doing (and in the OPs' case) the mirror modifier is even better then duplicating the mesh.