# How do I flip a leg?

Tags: modeling, objects

Okay so I am making a creature and I made one leg. I duplicated it but they are literally both left feet. How can I flip it so that the duplicate becomes a right foot?

Comment: I suggest using Mirror modifier instead of duplicating, especially for organic modeling like creatures with legs or without. Related - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43441/is-there-a-way-to-mirror-and-duplicate-in-one-action

Comment: I guess I've misunderstood your question a bit :). You want to mirror the mesh, not an armature. @Mr Zak 's link is very helpful, but you can still mirror the object using the **Ctrl+M** shortcut as in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

First set the *pivot point type* to ***3D Cursor*** and snap the cursor to the center of the grid (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>). Then in *Edit Mode* select the whole rig (<kbd>A</kbd>). Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, <kbd>RMB</kbd>. Then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>, type the axis (in my case Y) and -1. It'll mirror your leg along the desired axis. Then select the mirrored rig and press <kbd>W</kbd>-->*Flip Names*. It'll automatically name your legs properly with .R/.L.
[image]